# Select angular tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript

Is it possible to select Angular tags with JQuery? I am using the ui-select Angular component, it is inserted in HTML page like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="rec.currencyCode" on-select="ctrl.selectCurrencyCode(rec, $item)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ 'SelectCurrency' | resource:'GuiText' }}">
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.currencies">
        <span ng-bind-html="item.codeA3"></span><br />
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

When I try to select the tag with JQuery, these two selectors do not find the element:

```
$("ui-select").each(function () {
}

$("select").each(function () {
}
```

**UPDATE**. The code with JQuery is run from a typescript controller:

```
    validate(): boolean {
        var that = this;

        this.errors = [];

        var inputs = $("input[format='number']");
        inputs.each(function () {
            var str = $(this).val();
            if (str != null && str.length > 0) {
                var val = parseFloat(str);
                if (isNaN(val)) {
                    that.addError($(this).parent().attr("val-property"), "Hodnota není číslo");
                }
            }
        });

        var currencyCodes = $("ui-select");
        currencyCodes.each(function () {
            var str = $(this).val();
            console.log(this);
            console.log(str);
            if (str == null) {
                that.addError($(this).parent().attr("val-property"), "Není zadána měna");
            }
        });

        return this.errors.length == 0;
    }
```

Comment: try it from within chome - F12 > Console. You may not be able to access the element that fas.t

Comment: from where your are trying to access ..inside controller or from out of scope of module

Comment: I tried `$("ui-select").length` in Chrome console and it returns 0.

Comment: Are you sure the element is actually in the DOM when you're running your jQuery selector? Most likely issue here is that you're running this in the wrong part of the digest loop so there's nothing to select yet. (In general mixing jQuery and Angular like you're doing is a code smell -- there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do)

Comment: Did you already tried to wrap your jQuery inside a `$(document).ready()`function?

Comment: @fbid Could the ready function be used together with the validation function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, the `ui-select` element is replaced by angular with a `div` element so there is actually no `select` element for the combo box.

```
<div class="currencyCode ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-valid" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" ng-model="rec.currencyCode" on-select="ctrl.selectCurrencyCode(rec, $item)" data-original-title="" title="">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {


    var angularTag = $("ui-select");
    angularTag.each(function() {
      $('.result').html('DOM length:' + angularTag.length);
      console.log(angularTag);
    });


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ui-select ng-model="rec.currencyCode" on-select="ctrl.selectCurrencyCode(rec, $item)">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="{{ 'SelectCurrency' }}">
    <span ng-bind="$select.selected"></span>
  </ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.currencies">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.codeA3"></span>
    <br />
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>


<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Could the validation function be used together with the document ready function?

Comment: I tried to select the element, but it returns no elements. When I tried to add a class to the ui-select and select elements by the class name, the elements are found.

Comment: cant anser your question without more of your code version of jquery ? version of angular it will be also good to known :)

Comment: It is angular 1.4.9, jquery 2.2.0. I found inbetween out where the problem was, please see the other answer, angular translates the element name to a div.